# libgdx - moving a KinematicBody in a circular path

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to achieve a circular movement of `KinematicBody` around another body. I tryied this function:

```
public void updateCircular(float speed, Vector2 center){
    Vector2 radius = center.cpy().sub(this.body.getPosition());
    Vector2 force = radius.rotate90(1).nor().scl(speed);
    this.body.setLinearVelocity(force.x, force.y);
}
```

But it's work fine only for `DynamicBody` connected with `DistanceJoint`. Changing body type to `KinematicBody` changes the behavior of the body. The body ceases to move in a circular orbit and passes to a **spiral motion** (Constantly increases the radius as if the centrifugal force is consumed by it). I need as much as possible a perfect circular motion. How can I achieve this?
Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to just create a distance joint between some static body and your kinematics body. This way the body stays a certain radius from the other(creates a circle) and then you could just use set velocity to change its speed.

Comment: It doesn't work for KinematicBody. DistanceJoint affects only DynamicBody.

Comment: What makes you say that? And can you really not use a dynamic body if that is true?

Answer (score 0):

If the rotating body has to be a kinematic body, then to get uniform circular motion with fixed radius, we can add an extra velocity component perpendicular to the velocity vector. We can calculate the difference in distance of rotating body with the center. The velocity can be calculated by dividing this distance by time step per frame. This will move the body towards or outwards from center whenever rotating body is going outwards or coming inwards to the center. Add the below velocity to your calculation.

```
float dst=rotatingBody.getPosition().dst(pivotBody.getPosition());
//radius is the distance of center to the rotating body
float delta=dst-radius ;
//dt is time step per frame
float c2=delta/(dt); 
Vector2 centripetalVector=new Vector2(pivotBody.getPosition()).sub(rotatingBody.getPosition()).nor().scl(c2);
```

I have written a tutorial on how to achieve a rotating shield around a moving dynamic body as center in libgdx. It can be found [here](https://rotatingcanvas.com/move-box2d-body-in-circular-path-in-libgdx/) along with the full code.